# Powershell phone number formatting/normalizing

Tags: regex, powershell

I have an input list of user details (csv) for import into my Active Directory

Unfortunately the telephone numbers are in two formats, neither of which is required....

Format 1: UK area code and number with space e.g.

```
01232 123456
0141 333 4567
```

Format 2: Unformatted number e.g.

```
1232123456
1413334567
```

I would appreciate concise suggestions ideas for changing both the above formats into a common format as below:

```
01232123456
01413334567
```

I can remove whitespace easily simply using the following:

```
($number -replace ('\s+',''))
```

However my RegEx is limited and I'm sure there's a better way overall to format telephone numbers and maybe do some validation too - can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Something like `($number -replace '\s+').PadLeft(11,'0')` perhaps?

Comment: Yup works, but was hoping that there was a way to also validate the number a little better. I didn't make that clear though, sorry.

Comment: I’d try something like `('1232 456 789' -replace '\D' | where {$_ -match '0?(1232|141\d)\d{6}'}) -replace '^[1-9]\d{9}$','0$&'`